# Find the value of $\angle x$ without trigonometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Recently I watched a video by mindyourdecisions about solving this problem[image]

The sides marked with a dot are equal

[Link for the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ct_9l70Bf6o)

Find the value of $x$ ?

He solved this using trigonometry I am not an expert in trigonometry so it is not familiar for me to work with trigonometric ratios and the laws

My effort:
[image]

I constructed a rhombus by extending BA to E and tried to find angle $x$ but only I found was a few isosceles triangles. I also tried similar triangles. Nothing wouldn't help me to find the value of $x$ Anyone in this community could help me to find the value of $\angle x$ without trigonometry

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a link to the video? Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamRyman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ct_9l70Bf6o here is the link I also edited the question. Thank you

Comment: Yes it can be solved without trigonometry. I can share my solution but will first seek you to share your effort. What construction did you do and how far did you get?

Comment: What MndYourDecisions calls $y$ can easily be seen to equal $90^\circ-2x$. With that, $\angle BDA=90^\circ -6x$. *Knowing* form the video what will come out, you now have all angles in the figure. Then some of them are "accidentally" equal - does that help?

Comment: @MathLover I edited the question by adding my effort

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes I found that but how can I find the value

Comment: @Bometh Sorry, I can't think of a way to solve it algebraically; there's no way I can think of that's simpler than using construction or trigonometry in order to gain the necessary information needed to solve for $x$. The only way that I can think of solving this that's technically purely algebraic is by using the complex definitions of the trigonometric functions, but I don't think that will actually do any good. I wish I could help you further.

Comment: @WilliamRyman Thanks for your time

Comment: @Bometh No problem. I hope your question gets answered.

Comment: Here is a video that should help. Let me know if any questions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yxpbgn7LXAU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is another solution. Extend $AC$ and $BD$ and say they meet at $E$.

As $\angle ACB = 5x = \angle CEB + \angle CBE$, $\angle CEB = 4x$.

That leads to $BD = AB = AE$

Now choose point $F$ on $BD$ such that $\angle BCF = x$. Then we see $\angle DFC = \angle DCF = 2x, \angle CDE = 4x$.
$\implies CE = CD = DF$.

So it follows that $AC = BF = CF$

Now $\angle BDC = 180^\circ - 4x$ and $\angle ADB = \angle BAD = \frac12 (180^\circ - 4x)$

So $DA$ is angle bisector in isosceles triangle $\triangle CDF$ and hence it is perpendicular bisector of segment $CF$ and any point on the perpendicular bisector will be equidistant to points $C$ and $F$.
Therefore $AC = AF = CF$ and $\triangle ACF$ is equilateral. Hence $x = 10^\circ$.